# Array#to_s in Ruby 2.1 broke my code

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.1

This code broke on Ruby 2.1

```
class Test
  def to_s()
    "hi"
  end
end

puts [Test.new(), Test.new()].to_s
```

Ruby 1.9.3:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
$ /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby test.rb
[hi, hi]
```

Ruby 2.1:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-linux]
$ ruby test.rb
[#<Test:0x000000022ac400>, #<Test:0x000000022ac3d8>]
```

Is this documented somewhere? How can the old behavior be preserved?

Comment: As per documentation http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-to_s it states that it will return object's class encoding object's Id.

Comment: Same as in here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-to_s

Comment: @user944938 but the OP is providing his own implementation of to_s()

Comment: Here is it: "Ruby 2.0 uses #to_s as an alias to #inspect" https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8520  (straight from Yukihiro Matsumoto)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code:

```
puts [Test.new(), Test.new()].to_s
```

is a questionable use of `Array.to_s`. Instead I'd use:

```
puts [Test.new(), Test.new()].map(&:to_s)
```

While I can see that the first use makes sense, the second use makes more sense and should work in any version of Ruby.

Comment: I figured there's a way around this, I guess there isn't. Thanks

Comment: I agree with this. When you want to call a method on an object inside an Enumerable I think you should have to enter into the Object and call the method internally using something like `map` in this case. I think the original implementation is a little less in congruence with OO design than the 2.0 version.

Comment: Also just as a note `map(&:to_s)` is actually faster than `Array#to_s` by more than a marginal amount. Although this simple implementation is inconsequential mass implementation could show as much as 60% difference in performance. Althouhg please note the difference in out put `Array#to_s` in this case will be `"[hi,hi]"` where as `map(&:to_s)` will be `["hi","hi"]`

Answer (score 1):

On ruby 2.1.5:

```
class Test
  def to_s
    "hi"
  end

  alias inspect to_s # add this line
end

puts [Test.new, Test.new].to_s
#=> [hi, hi]
```

This seems like a bug to me. If it is intended behavior, that is really annoying.

Comment: I don't want to override inspect. I use it for a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `to_s`. `puts` does the work for you

```
puts [Test.new(), Test.new()]
# hi
# hi
```

If you want the brackets, that's what `inspect` is for (in which case it makes sense that you would need to define `Test#inspect`).